# TensorFlow broadcasting of RaggedTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How do I subtract a tensor from ragged tensor?

Example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf    # TensorFlow 2.6

X = tf.ragged.constant([[[3, 1], [3]],
                        [[2], [3, 4]]], ragged_rank=2)
y = tf.constant([[1], [2]])
X-y
```

Expected result:

```py
[[[2, 0], [1]],
 [[1], [1, 2]]]
```

However, it returns an error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'Unable to broadcast: dimension size mismatch in dimension'
1
b'lengths='
2
b'dim_size='
2, 2
```

I know I can do it row-by-row:

```py
result = []
if X.shape[0] is not None:  # Placeholders have None everywhere -> range(None) raises an exception -> this condition
    for row in range(X.shape[0]):
        result.append(X[row] - y)
    result = tf.stack(result)
```

However, this works only in the eager mode - in graph mode, I get:

```py
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable
```

because the code gets executed only conditionally...

What works is to hard-code the count of rows:

```py
for row in range(2):
    result.append(X[row] - y)
result = tf.stack(result)
```

But that doesn't generalize well.

I also know I can write:

```py
X - tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1)
```

But that returns a result for "transposed" y:

```py
[[[2, 0], [2]],
 [[0], [1, 2]]]
```

I also know I can also use:

```py
def subtract(x):
    return x - y

tf.map_fn(subtract, X)
```

But when using the result in graph mode, I get:

```
ValueError: Unable to broadcast: unknown rank
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the desired effect, try the following:

`X - tf.expand_dims(y, axis=2)`

Note that we only added `tf.expand_dims()` on the original `y` which is still `tf.constant([[1], [2]])`

The following desired result is obtained (tested on TF 2.6 version):

`<tf.RaggedTensor [[[2, 0], [2]], [[0], [1, 2]]]>`

As can be seen in the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf # TensorFlow 2.6
print("TensorFlow version:", tf. version )
X = tf.ragged.constant([[[3, 1], [3]],
                        [[2], [3, 4]]], ragged_rank=2)
y = tf.constant([[1], [2]])
print(X-tf.expand_dims(y, axis=2))
```

With output:

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[2, 0], [2]], [[0], [1, 2]]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
x = tf.ragged.constant([[[3, 1], [3]],
                        [[2], [3, 4]]])  # shape(2,None,None)

x = tf.RaggedTensor.from_uniform_row_length(x.values, uniform_row_length=2) # shape(2,2,None)
```

Output of `x - y`

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[2, 0], [1]],
 [[1], [1, 2]]]>
```

A preferable way would be to construct `x` as a tensor with ragged rank 1 from the beginning

```
x = tf.ragged.constant([[3, 1], [3],
                        [2], [3, 4]], ragged_rank=1)  # shape(4,None)
x = tf.RaggedTensor.from_uniform_row_length(x, uniform_row_length=2)  # shape(2,2,None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `tf.RaggedTensor`s are a bit flaky.

**tldr**; Operations between `tf.RaggedTensor` and `tf.Tensor` do not always as expected. Sometimes converting `tf.Tensor` to a `tf.RaggedTensor` does the job.

The solution is as follows. `X` can remain as is,

```
X = tf.ragged.constant([[[3, 1], [3]],
                        [[2], [3, 4]]], ragged_rank=2)
```

which has a shape (`X.shape`) of `[2, None, None]`.

### Solution

Next we convert `y` to a `tf.RaggedTensor` as follows.

```
y = tf.ragged.constant(pylist=[[[1], [2]]], ragged_rank=1)
```

which has a shape (`y.shape`) of `[1, None, 1]`. And,

`X-y` gives,

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[2, 0], [1]], [[1], [1, 2]]]>
```

### Caveat

For `y` a `ragged_rank=2` will lead to the following error.

```
InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'Unable to broadcast: dimension size mismatch in dimension'
2
b'lengths='
1, 1, 1, 1
b'dim_size='
2, 1, 1, 2
```

which I don't fully comprehend. The best way to avoid this is by having as many dimensions fixed as possible. And this will become more complex as the dimensionality of your tensors grow. For this, you can use `RaggedTensor` constructs such as `from_uniform_row_length`  (More in for [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#uniform_inner_dimensions) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#uniform_inner_dimensions))