# How do I subtract a tensor from ragged tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensor, ragged-tensors

I am asking a question very similar to that of [TensorFlow broadcasting of RaggedTensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295934/tensorflow-broadcasting-of-raggedtensor)

Basically, I am doing machine learning, and one data sample consists of a list of lists of coordinates, where each list of coordinates represents a drawing stroke on a canvas. One such sample might be,

```
[
[[2,3], [2,4], [3,6], [4,8]], 
[[7,3], [10,9]], 
[[10,12], [14,17], [13,15]]
]
```

I would like to normalize these coordinates by subtracting by the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. Specifically, I want to find the mean and standard deviation of all the x-coordinates (index=0) and y-coordinates (index=1), respectively.
I got these values by

```
list_points=tf.ragged.constant(list_points)
STD=tf.math.reduce_std(list_points, axis=(0,1))
mean=tf.reduce_mean(list_points, axis=(0,1))
```

STD and mean both have shape of (2,)

Now, I want to subtract the mean from list_points (this is the sample list of lists of coordinates), but it seems that for ragged_rank=3, I can only subtract by a scalar or a tensor that covers every single data point. Is there an easy way that I can simply subtract the RaggedTensor by a Tensor of shape (2,)?

I have tried to simply subtract mean from list_points directly, but whatever I do, I get this error:

ValueError: pylist has scalar values depth 3, but ragged_rank=3 requires scalar value depth greater than 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `ragged_rank` is 1 in fact. Thus `tf.reduce_mean` can be used as follows

```py
list_points = tf.ragged.constant(
    [
        [[2,3], [2,4], [3,6], [4,8]], 
        [[7,3], [10,9]], 
        [[10,12], [14,17], [13,15]]
    ],
    ragged_rank=1,
    dtype=tf.float32
)
list_points.shape
# TensorShape([3, None, 2])

mean = tf.reduce_mean(list_points, axis=[0, 1])
# tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([7.22222222, 8.55555556])>

std = tf.reduce_mean(list_points**2, axis=[0, 1]) - tf.reduce_mean(list_points, axis=[0, 1])**2
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([19.72839506, 23.80246914])>
```

We can subtract (add, multiply, etc) from a ragged tensor of ragged rank 1 an ordinary tensor of rank 1 if their first dimensions coincides.

```py
list_points - mean
# <tf.RaggedTensor [[[-5.2222223, -5.5555553],
#   [-5.2222223, -4.5555553],
#   [-4.2222223, -2.5555553],
#   [-3.2222223, -0.55555534]], [[-0.22222233, -5.5555553],
#                                [2.7777777, 0.44444466]]  ,
#  [[2.7777777, 3.4444447],
#   [6.7777777, 8.444445],
#   [5.7777777, 6.4444447]]]>
```

This is possible because under the hood of the raged tensor of ragged rank 1 we have an ordinary tensor

```py
list_points.values.shape
# TensorShape([9, 2])
```

For `ragged_rank > 1` case we can attract [`tf.math.segment_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/segment_mean)
that is more tricky.

Comment: I already am able to obtain the STD and mean. That is not my question. I want to subtract the mean and STD from list_points. In this example, it should result in:
[
        [[2-7.22, 3-8.55], [2-7.22, 4-8.55], ...]
        ...
        [..., [13-7.22, 15-8.55]]
]

Comment: @AidenYun I modified the answer.

Comment: Hey Alexey, I just found that you have a GitHub for CTC! What a coincidence! Do you know how I can implement CTC such that there are no blanks? I do not need them because I never have consecutive symbols.

Comment: if you see this can you comment back or email me at aiden.t.yun@gmail.com? Thanks! @AlexeyTochin

Comment: For CTC loss you can create for example a separate discussion on stackoverflow on in the github project issues. Short answer is that the primary role of blanks in CTC is filling gaps between real predictions. Separating repeated tokens (which are to be swapped) is the secondary role in classic CTC that can be disabled in both tensorflow and my implementations.

Comment: What I want to do is disable the first role (and the second role, because I don't need it). It's fine, though, I just used a hack to get around it.